# How to get number and calculating operator from string

Tags: regex

I want to extract numer and calculator operator from string.

For example, I have a string like below:

```
1m-2m+(2.2*3mm)
```

I want to get `1-2+(2.2*3)` which will only contains number and `+-*/` and other operators.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I thought to achieve through regex. But, not sure the correct regex pattern.

Comment: it sounds a very unstructured approach to the problem... but if you just need strip off characters from string not being digits, math signs and parenthesis you could attempt with a replace with a regex like: `[^-+*/()\d]` and replacement as empty string

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Is there a way to include digits?

Comment: `Replace` may not statable, can it achieve by regex match, I think out like `(\d+|\-|\+|\/|\*|\.|\(|\))`, but it seems also not statable.

Comment: `sed -E 's/[!^m]*//gm;t;d' <<< "1m-2m+(2.2*3mm)"`  ( https://regex101.com/r/mFBdi6/1 )

Comment: the regex I showed it's just a negated characters class saying: all characters not being: digits, parenthesis, +, -, *, /; must match and be considered to be replaced with an empty string. If you want to get there with match only instead of replace, you need to negate that class and list all matches to be glued together in the new string but it's a very awful approach. I think you should instead state what's your platform where you are using that regex because I'm quite sure you are following the wrong path going with match only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simple case you describe I suggest not to cope with regex patterns and process the text string character by character:

Let's use Python3 (as easy to read and understand programming language):

```
list_of_text_lines = [
    '1m-2m+(2.2*3mm)'   , # test text 1
    '5z=25x-20y'        , # test text 2
    '11 != 12 ; 12 < 13', # test text 3   
]
for text_line in list_of_text_lines:
    s1 = ''.join( [ 
          char for char in text_line 
       if char in "0.123456789+-*/=()<>^!;" ] ) 
    print(s1)
# gives: 
"""
1-2+(2.2*3)
5=25-20
11!=12;12<13
"""
```

where you can intuitively and easy adapt the code to the details of what you need.